# Microsoft Bot transparent authentication

Tags: bots, botframework

I just started exploring Bot Framework and I case that I wasn't able to find an answer for came in my head.

I want my bot to say something like: "Hi " when the user type hi, hello etc, but at the same time I don't want to prompt the user to sign-in again, because he already did it when accessing the page. How to achieve that when I insert the web chat as iframe?

The user is authenticated using AAD. I found [this](https://stephaneeyskens.wordpress.com/2017/01/04/microsoft-bot-framework-transparent-authentication-with-the-webchat-control/) article, but i wasn't able to make it working, idk why.

Thanks in advance for you answers.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot  The article you mentioned was built using a library built on top of AuthBot

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, you can use the [BackChannel mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel). With this, you can pass messages from/to the WebChat Control from/to your page. And more on your question, maybe you can pass some user data to the WebChat when user is logged.